# how to pronunce >>> bitwise operator in code/program?

Tags: pronunciation

I know the pronounciation of >> is "right shift"....but this...

Can anyone help me here? I am also very interested in other bitwise operator's pronunciation

Comment: Do you mean the pronunciation or the name? If you know its name, we can probably help you with the pronunciation

Comment: Looks like the name is "unsigned right shift operator". The first word is pronounced /ˌʌn'saınd/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is not English Learning question here.  The name of an operator is specific to the particular computer language and isn't part of general English vocabulary.

Comment: @gotube Thank you, I think that's it!!  "unsigned right shift operator".

Comment: @gotube answer below and I will choose your answer. Thank you! And also could you please tell me where did you find the answer? I want to learn more about it

Comment: @ColinChou I just googled something like "What does the >>> bitwise operator do?" I looked up a few answers and they agreed on the name. I'm glad you have your answer, but in future, you should do that basic level of research yourself before asking here.

Comment: I did seached several times with" how to pronounce >>>". I learned from you that I googled it the wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: Being self-taught, I remember in the 1980s wondering how to pronounce e.g. `#0f0f0f` or `#!/bin/bash`. I sympathise.

Comment: I think really that if you are needing to read literal code stuff aloud you are probably with other coders and you can pick things up by listening, or they will tell you what to say. Otherwise talk in normal English, i.e. say 'increment the variable here' and not 'var plus plus'.

Comment: I feel this question deserves more attention, but I don't have permission to create an answer.
You say: "I know the pronounciation of >> is 'right shift'"; but it isn't. The MEANING of >> is right shift. It doesn't have a pronunciation. Program code generally doesn't, because it's not something that people (usually) read aloud.
Consider HTML (Web page code), like <p>.  You might say "pee" (if the element context is known), or "angle bracket p close angle bracket", or "less than p greater than", etc. There is no official rule, because programming/markup languages are not designed to be spoken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the name is "unsigned right shift operator". The first word is pronounced /ˌʌn'saınd/.